# Finding a variable P for which a sum converges

Tags: limits-and-convergence, divergent-series

I need guidance in finding a variable P for which $ \sum _{n=4}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{n\ln \left(n\right)-n}{\ln \left(n!\right)}\right)^p $ converges, or proof that there doesn't exist such P variable.

I've tried the direct comparison test, by defining the sequence $ b_n=\:\left(\frac{n\ln \left(n\right)-n}{\ln \left(n!\right)}\right)^p $ and the sequence $ a_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{\ln \left(n\right)}\right)^p $.

From here I'm not sure how to prove that $\sum _{n=4}^{\infty }\:a_n$ diverges.

Comment: Have you tried replacing $\ln(n!)$ with the Stirling formula?

Comment: Have you tried the divergence test on $a_n$?

Comment: @DieterKadelka I've tried using the Stirling formula, but I didn't see where it can lead.

Comment: @GabeConant I've tried using the direct comprasion test on $a_n$ with the sequence $ (1-(1/n))^p $ which I know diverges, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: To show that $\Sigma (1-(1/n))^p = \infty$ assume that $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and use the $\zeta$-function.

Comment: @AlapanDas I've been taught that if $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\sqrt[n]{a_n}\right)=1$ the root test is indecisive, can you please explain further?

Comment: Yes you are right. Take the two series for example. 1) $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$ and 2)$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^2}$. For both the series $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=1$. But, at $x=1$, $f(x)$ doesn't converge, but $g(x)$ does.

Comment: In your question, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{2n(1-\frac{1}{ln(n)})+1})^{\frac{-p}{n}}≈(1-\frac{1}{2n})^{\frac{-p}{n}}$. This becomes similar to asking whether $\sum_{n=0} (1-\frac{1}{2n})^p$ is convergent or not. And obviously this is divergent.

Comment: @AlapanDas I don't know how to prove that $ \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^p $ diverges

Comment: For , large $n$, $(1-\frac{1}{2n})≈1$, hence, it's equivalent to $\sum_{k=0} x^k$.